# Problem creating pdf output using latexmk

Tags: pdftex, latexmk

For the last 2 hours I have been struggling to create a pdf output from a `.tex` file using `latexmk`. I am following the instructions given in [this document](https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html#) for Windows users and all the output files are being created successfully except the pdf file.

The following message is being generated after I call `latexmk -pdf` from the Git Bash:

```
Transcript written on 2d-row-pic.log.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Log file says output to '2d-row-pic.dvi'
Latexmk: applying rule 'dvipdf'...
Rule 'dvipdf': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      '2d-row-pic.dvi'
   Rule(s) that have been run and require run of dependent rule:
      'pdflatex' which requires run of 'dvipdf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'dvipdf'
------------
For rule 'dvipdf', running '&do_viewfile(  )' ...
------------
Running 'dvipdf  "2d-row-pic.dvi" "2d-row-pic.pdf"'
------------
sh: dvipdf: command not found
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  dvipdf: Command for 'dvipdf' gave return code 32512
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
```

From the message log, I can see that `dvipdf` command is missing, but I don't know how to fix this issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: why on earth is your document or latexmk requiring dvipdf? And why does your document create a dvi at all? What happens if you compile your document simply with `pdflatex 2d-row-pic`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, `pdflatex 2d-row-pic` also produces the dvi file and not the pdf!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I see where the mistake is! My first line in the `.tex` file is `%&latex` and removing this fixes the issue!